# Using git, how to do a 'use theirs' during a conflict?

Tags: git, merge

With git, how do I do a "use theirs" type branch merge command? This command should just overwrite my local version with the origin's version.

Comment: 415 questions, and less than half accepted?

Comment: @mitch 2 questions and both accepted?

Comment: Found this in my search; I'll just leave it here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html

Answer (score 5):

To replace your master with origin's master:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -M master old-master
$ git checkout --track -b master origin/master
```

The `git-merge` manpage defines the 'ours' strategy as (emphasis added)

> **MERGE STRATEGIES**
>
> *ours*
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the result of the merge
>     is **always the current branch head.** It is meant to be used to
>     supersede old development history of side branches.

If you want a remote branch to win, create a tracking branch, check it out, and `git merge -s ours ...` from there.